# How to create a subprocess in Python, send multiple commands based on previous output

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a program which initiates a connection to a remote machine, then dynamically sending multiple commands to it by monitoring the response. Instead of using pexpect, what else can I use? I am trying to use subprocess.Popen, but communicate() method will kill the process.

Pexpect version: 2.4, http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html

Referring to the API for subprocess in:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate
Popen.communicate(input=None)
Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate**. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow](/)! This question is a little short on information. Please take the [tour](/tour) and read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Also try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) that reproduces the above issue.

Comment: You're going to want to post your specific code to get any tangible code recommendations.  What's your aversion to pexpect?  What will kill the communicate() with using subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the subprocess documentation to understand the basics [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

You could do something like this ... 
Again, this is just a pointer... this approach may/may not be a best fit for your use case.

Explore -> and Test to find what works for you!

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

class Command(object):
    """ Generic Command Interface ."""

    def execute(self, cmd):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
        exit_value = proc.poll()
        if exit_value:
            logger.error('Command execution failed. Command : %s' % cmd)
        return exit_value, stdout_value


if __name__ == '__main__':

    cmd = Command()
    host = ''  # HOSTNAME GOES HERE
    cmd_str = '' # YOUR COMMAND GOES HERE
    cmdline = 'ksh -c "ssh root@{0} "{1}""'.format(host, cmd_str)  
    exit_value, stdout_value = cmd.execute(cmdline)

    if exit_value == 0:
        # execute other command/s
        # you basically use the same logic as above
    else:
        # return Or execute other command/s
```